# Creating object based off of variable number of array values

Tags: javascript

Lets say I've got a JavaScript array like this:

```
var arr=['first','second','third'];
```

And a value like this:

```
var val='bacon';
```

How can I make it so the array and value get translated into an object like this:

```
var obj[first][second][third]='bacon';
```

**Two Important Catches:**

1) The number of elements in the array is always different.  So it could just be ['first','second'] or ['first','second','third','fourth'] etc...

2) obj will already exist and needs to not be overwritten with the new value.  For example `obj[first][somethingelse]='eggs'` may already exist, and still needs to exist after `obj[first][second][third]='bacon'` is added.

I've tried to come up with various loops and recursive functions to do this.  But the variable number of elements in the array keeps tripping me up.

Comment: so what if there are two arrays `[first][second][third]`  ? is this possible ? And show some code atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array.reduce` to simplify the process:

```
var object = {a: true}, value = 'bacon'; 

['first','second','third'].reduce(function(a, b, index, array) {
  return a[b] = index === array.length - 1 ? value : (a[b] || {});
}, object);

console.log(object);
```

This takes the initial object and every time returns a new object assigned to a particular property name (if there was no object like that before). As long as object is just a reference, the new created object is set as your object property, and the same object is returned as a parameter `a`. When it reaches the last element in the array, the value is returned instead of a new object.

Comment: Fails the `obj[first][somethingelse]='eggs'` test - you overwrite existing objects. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyKZZj

Comment: Fixed if you replace `value : {}` with `value : (a[b] || {})`

Comment: exactly what I was going to do... Thank you for the comments. At first I was thinking it needs to override, did not pay enough attention. My bad

Comment: well just a test to show it is not empty. Could be whatever

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!  Thank you for being part of humanity @smnbbrv

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this???

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr=['first','second','third'];
    var myObj = {};
    for(item in arr) {
        myObj[arr[item]] = 'test-'+item
    }

        console.log(myObj)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/mw4hm5ma/4/